# How should I patch holes in a waterproof/breathable jacket?

Tags: diy, repairs, waterproof-clothing, jackets

I have a waterproof/breathable rain jacket which has a few holes in it (caused by a minor bicycle crash, in case that information is relevant). They are not too big, about 5mm across.  How can I patch these holes?  It doesn't have to look too pretty, I'd just like it to be reasonably waterproof.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it doesn't need to be pretty, a cost effective option is spinnaker repair tape (nylon cloth tape, for example, see products on [this page](http://www.admiralpsp.co.uk/psp/products/sail-repair-tapes.html)). It is designed for repairs to yacht sails so it is durable, weatherproof and should survive a machine wash (but it wont be breathable). Stick a piece over the hole on the front and back of the fabric.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea.  I don't really care if it’s not breathable since it will just be over a small section of the jacket.  Now I'll just have to find a sailing store in my land locked city...

I'll give an update when I try this to let everyone know how well it worked (might be a while though since I want to get a new jacket I can wear around town first).

I'm open to other suggestions until then though.

Answer (score 2):

Some stores have waterproof glue which you could use to fix a waterproof patch. [An example](http://www.mec.ca/AST/ShopMEC/Tents/TentAccessories/PRD~5019-835/trousse-de-reparation-sil-fix-de-mcnett.jsp?bmLocale=en&bmForm=setLanguageCookie&bmFormID=jlAQkEY&bmSubmit=SetLanguageCookie).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Shawn.  I think the specific one you mentioned says it is for silicone treated surfaces, but the same website had some similar products which I think will work for me.  Do you have any experience with these types of patches?

Comment: @BigGeneral No experience, but I just bought some to repair my tent so I will be getting experience very soon!

Comment: Hi Shawn! The link to that patch is broken, at least in my browser, though it leads to a store which I think is the right place, I tried to see if I could edit it, but a "waterproof patch" search produced many things and I'm not sure which you meant. If you want, it would be helpful to link to it again, and maybe give a quick description. Also, since it looks like you used it a few years ago, I'd really like to know how it worked for you. Thanks!

Comment: @Sue I can no longer find the glue I linked to... Sorry, but I'll just have to remove the link. If I remember correctly, I was referring to the same kind of glue you find in tent-repair kits, and the same kind of patch as well. It didn't work too well for me after all though. The instructions said to do it in the sunshine to help the glue dry faster, but I had serious sun and it dried so fast I didn't manage to put it on straight and it was a disaster :p

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I'm sorry about the disaster, and hope you found something else that worked. I can clear away my comments if you want, I didn't mean to make your answer all messy! :)

Comment: @Sue I don't think that's necessary. For the curious, in the end I gave my tent to a professional and had it fix. Pretty pricey, but I no longer had time to do it myself :( At least he did a very good job :)