# What's the best way to apply patches to partially waterproof softshell jackets?

Tags: clothing, repairs, rain-gear

In a bike accident, I managed to damage a softshell jacket. The damage consists of some smaller holes, and the manufacturer provided me with a patch kit that is basically a piece of the material that is large enough be cut into patches for all the individual holes.

What is the best (i.e. most waterproof) way to sew/apply these patches without too much rain getting in through the seams?

*Edit: I know that the question is really similar to [How should I patch holes in a waterproof/breathable jacket?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/951/how-should-i-patch-holes-in-a-waterproof-breathable-jacket?rq=1), but my situation is slightly different: I already have the material and am just wondering how to best use it.*

*Edit 2: I just noticed that some confusion might come from the fact that my softshell jacket actually has/is made of some membrane material and promoted as somewhat waterproof (5000mm hydrostatic head). (See [Hardshell vs. Softshell jackets](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/5518/hardshell-vs-softshell-jackets/5519#5519) .) That's why I am worried about losing some of the waterproofness.*

Comment: Softshell jackets aren't really water proof anyway? Typically anyway. What jacket is it?

Comment: @Liam Mine seemed waterproof enough in light rain or short phases of heavier rain, though I haven't been wearing it for longer time in really heavy rain. If the answer is "Softshell jackets aren't that waterproof, so just sew it on and don't mind a few additional drops getting in!", then that would be fine with me, too. The jacket is one from elkline.de, though I doubt that the manufacturer is widely known outside Germany.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stitch and seam seal.  As Liam noted, softshells aren't really waterproof.  There are plenty of products you could use to glue the patch and it would be more waterproof than the rest of your jacket.  Unfortunately it would also be stiffer.  When you apply a stiff material to a flexible one it will wear at the edges and make new holes.

When you stitch, use a sewing machine unless you are extremely good with hand stitching.  Be careful with the tension because softshells won't take much abuse.